# htaccess rewrite rule for Forbidding urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not really new to htaccess rewrites, but today I have seen a rule which I've not seen before:

```
# Access block for folders
RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
```

This rule is part of the [Typo3 htaccess](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess) file.

What does the "?:" mean? Is this some kind of back reference? And what do the underlines stand for?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule `RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]` could be divided into 2 rules for better understanding. like:

```
RewriteRule _recycler_/ - [F]
```

AND

```
RewriteRule _temp_/ - [F]
```

***Now let us understand what does that mean:***

- You could see its a shortcut method to make 1 rule out of 2 rules.
- We could use regex to match multiple patterns and perform same kind of action on URIs which are falling in same criteria(which is matched by regex).
- In this case we are trying to match `_`(literal character) followed by `(?:recycler|temp)`. Where `?:` stands up for a non-capturing group. So whatever comes into this section`(?:.......)` will NOT come in backreference capability. Its basically matching string/text `recycler` OR `temp` in regex which is preceded and followed by `_`
- Now comes what is capturing group: in .htaccess we can use capability of capture matched values which we can use them later eg--> `$1` for getting 1st captured value(stored in memory), we could say non-capturing group tells that we want to match a regex but DO NOT store that into memory(because we DO NOT want to use it later onwards into our program).

***Here is an example of capturing group rules in htaccess rules:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(first|second)/(.*)?$ $1.php?$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***Explanation of above example:*** Its simply makes 2 capturing groups, 1st will have either first OR second, 2nd capturing group will have anything(because of we used .*) in it, so while rewriting part we are using `$1` and `$2` to get there values. You could clearly see that we could use these values in condition part as well(which becomes in backend like: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/first.php` OR `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/second.php`).

***Here is an example of non-capturing groups in htaccess Rules:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:first|second)/(third/fourth)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

***Explanation of above example:*** We could see that we are matching `first` OR `second` in rule side so now value of $1 will be either third OR fourth this time since we used non-capturing group for first/second. So backend condition check will become like: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/third.php` OR `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT/fourth.php`

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!